# Email body replace * with numbers

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have an email with * , **  in the body and some check boxes in a userform. If I select some check boxes, it will put in the email body :

```
* text1
** text2
...
* text24
** text25
```

When I want to reply I want to replace * with 1,2,3.... and delete ** . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by the 1,2,3 but something like this...?

```
Function RemoveStars(strInput As String) As String

    Dim intCount As Integer
    intCount = 1
    Stop
    RemoveStars = Replace(strInput, Chr(42) & Chr(42), "")
    Do While InStr(RemoveStars, Chr(42)) <> 0
        RemoveStars = Replace(RemoveStars, Chr(42), intCount, 1, 1)
        intCount = intCount + 1
    Loop

End Function
```